# How to highlight the color in the cell wherever the condition is not met in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and I'm writing VBA code that displays a message before saving an excel file based on a condition, the file is to be saved if the condition is fulfilled, and it does not save the file if the condition is not met.

What I want to do is, I want the file should be saved even the condition is not met, but it should highlight the color in the cell wherever the condition is not met.

How to accomplish this in VBA? Coluld someone help me..

I have provided below the sample excel and the code.

**Excel**

```
Person    ID          Condition
A       Yes / No      C should be blank if C/B is N in ID. 
                      C should be filled if A/B is Y in ID
B       Yes / No    

C
```

**code**

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
' C should be blank if A/B is N.
    If Application.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value = "N" Or Application.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C3").Value = "N" Then
        
        If Application.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C4").Value <> "" Then
            Cancel = True
            MsgBox "C should be blank if A/B is N"
       End If
    ElseIf Application.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value = "Y" Or Application.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C3").Value = "Y" Then
        
        If Application.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C4").Value = "" Then
            Cancel = False
            MsgBox "C should be filled if  A and C3 is Y"
       End If
    
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use [Conditional Formatting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-information-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us#:~:text=1%20Select%20the%20data%20that%20you%20want%20to,to%20apply%20and%20click%20OK%20.%20See%20More)?

Comment: @user692942, any idea how to accomplish this using VBA?

Comment: My point was do you even need to do it using VBA as conditional formatting is built-in and can be set up pretty easily without any programming required.